# What part of the computer renders text? Hardware or Software?

Tags: graphics, text, assembly, bios

For example, if i make a very simple bootloader that runs a "hello world" program (as the operating system), where is the graphical representation of the text processed.  The the GPU render the text, or the the hardware.  Is basic text input and output hard-coded in either the BIOS or processor, or is it integrated in assembly/programming langauge?

Comment: I'd call it hardware, but who knows anymore.

Comment: It seems you are assuming IBM-PC hardware?

Comment: Not sure why this is closed.  It's a perfectly reasonable (and interesting) question related to programming.  You need to know a little about the machine in order to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GPU can be in the processor or in the discrete card or even the motherboard. Basic I/O is done via the framebuffer in whatever handles it and is memory mapped by the BIOS usually to 0xb8000. To get simple I/O you just write the ascii characters to the framebuffer and the card will just output them to the screen (in a basic OS like you said).

It can be accomplished in any low level language that allows you to directly address memory values and can be compiled into native code.

For text you see on your screen (like this text) that's typically software's job as there are fonts, styles and other things to deal with. This is usually handled via basic API's exported by the operating system that allow screen drawing or by the drivers themselves.

Comment: does the graphic card have a decoder then so it can convert from binary to ascii characters?  and does the grahpic card have a fixed "image" of what each character should look like?

Comment: pretty much what im asking is where is the "file" or system that tells the computer what each character should look like

Comment: The graphics card has an internal bitmap for each basic character for basic I/O. If you want fancy text you need to write your own code to change each pixel on the screen by altering this bitmap. It gets quite complicated if you want anything more than basic I/O because of resolutions and color depth. By the way basic I/O also supports colored text.

Comment: Not true.  Switching to another text style doesn't require graphical mode.  The character generator can be pointed at RAM (populated by whatever bitmap you choose to create).

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I meant the kind's of text you would see on the screen such as in a browser, not CLI text which is usually what you get but I guess it all depends on how you look at it.

Answer (score 3):

In PC land, there's a character generator in the video subsystem.  Takes the 8-bit character values out of video RAM, uses the character definition matrices (which can either be in ROM, or pointed to ones in RAM for custom character sets) and generates the display.  This only applies to pure text mode.  Graphical mode is a completely different animal in regards to video RAM layout (and also starts to involve the GPU, etc).